# SQL: SUM() not working when apply not equal condition

Tags: sql

this is my voucers table below with query. i want to sum credit column without pay_action_id value when 2. But the query **output** is null given.

```
SELECT sum(credit) from voucers where pay_action_id<>2

+------------------------------+
|debit | credit | pay_action_id|
+------------------------------+
|40.00 | 4.00   | null         |
+------------------------------+
|0.00  | 46.00  | 2            |
+------------------------------+
|0.00  | 34.00  | 1            |
+------------------------------+
|40.00 | 0.00   | null         |
+------------------------------+
```

****output**:** will be 38 if solved

Comment: Tag your question only with the database you are using.

Comment: Removed conflicting database tags, pls add the one back that you actually use!

Answer (score 2):

As with most other comparisons, `<>` filters out `NULL` values.  If you want them, you need to explicitly include them.  One way is:

```
SELECT sum(credit) 
FROM voucers 
WHERE pay_action_id <> 2 OR pay_action_id IS NULL;
```

Both MySQL and Postgres have `NULL`-safe comparison operators.  Postgres supports the standard:

```
WHERE pay_action_id IS DISTINCT FROM 2
```

MySQL has a bespoke operator:

```
WHERE NOT (pay_action_id <=> 2)
```